# AngularJs multiple params in a state

Tags: angularjs, parameters

I want to send a multiple param items but it is not working.First one is working(I can see value on controller) If i send it alone.But when i send multiple params it is not working.

It is working`params : {name : name}`

Not working  `params: {name : name,filter : filter}`

Error is filter is not defined.My page is state page.

Comment: Please provide a little more code and information. How is your routing working (Do you use `ui-router`?)? How does your controller accept and use the expected params? How do you `send` these params?

Comment: I send data with 'ui-sref'.It loads data both name and filter.But when the page reloads ,stateparams values are not working

Comment: Again, please provide the code in question.